# Chaning column total at the bottom from two different columns average

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get a percentage of two different columns and apply it to the bottom of the FT% total. It should be 0.722 as 13/18 = 0.722 and not the average of the actual FT% in that column.

[Power BI picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndEE0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out, if anyone else was wondering. You need to do it as a quick measure and just rename the measure what you wanted in my case FT%.

FT% = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Milwaukee Bucks (2-3) Table'[FT]),
    SUM('Milwaukee Bucks (2-3) Table'[FTA])
)